# Is there something wrong with onKeyUp (down) with API=22?

Tags: android, android-build

I don't get if this is a bug. I used to catch key press events on the menu button, and noticed that - after switching to v22 and building with 22.0.1 - it didn't work anymore.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    Log.i("keydown", "generic");
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) { Log.i("keydown", "menu"); }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    Log.i("keyup", "generic");
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) { Log.i("keyup", "menu"); }
    return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
}
```

My console stays empty. Any ideas? Both on why and on how to workaround.

Comment: nothing mentioned in the docs about that?

Comment: @Alex.F I couldn't find anything, nor someone else who faced this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep there *is* something wrong - bug has been recognized and its fix has been set on a future release of `appcompat-v7`. It is related to `AppCompatActivity` and should not affect the framework `Activity` of course.

See [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=159795&can=1&q=onKeyDown&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars) for reference.